# Meeting a pip requirement using an alternative module

Tags: python, module, pip, python-3.7, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install a python module, 'pyAudioProcessing' (https://github.com/jsingh811/pyAudioProcessing) on my Linux Mint distribution, and one of the items in requirements.txt is causing issues: `python-magic-bin==0.4.14`. When I run `pip3 install -e pyAudioInstaller`, I get an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-magic-bin==0.4.14 (from pyAudioProcessing==1.1.5) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-magic-bin==0.4.14 (from pyAudioProcessing==1.1.5)
```

The same error appears if I try to manually install the module using `pip3 install python-magic-bin`. The module installs without issues on my windows machine.

pypi.org lets me download files for it manually, however only Windows and MacOS .whl files are available. I tried simply removing the requirement from the list, but that resulted in a large number of other errors to appear, so I assume the module is legitimately required.

Thee is another module called `python-magic-debian-bin` that I can download. Is there a simple way to convince pyAudioInstaller to use this other module instead of the original? Like can I somehow rename `python-magic-debian-bin` to `python-magic-bin` and hope it works out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`python-magic-bin` 0.4.14](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic-bin/0.4.14/#files) provides wheels for OSX, w32 and w64, but not for Linux. And there is no source code at PyPI.

You need to install it from [github](https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic.git
```

As for `pyAudioProcessing` I can see 2 ways to install it:

1. Clone [the repository](https://github.com/jsingh811/pyAudioProcessing) and edit `requirements/requirements.txt`, replace `python-magic-bin==0.4.14` with `pip install git+https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic.git#egg=python-magic`;
2. Install [requirements](https://github.com/jsingh811/pyAudioProcessing/blob/master/requirements/requirements.txt) manually and then install `pyAudioProcessing` [without dependencies](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-deps):

   `pip install --no-deps pyAudioProcessing`

or

```
pip install --no-deps git+https://github.com/jsingh811/pyAudioProcessing.git
```